# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: permission denied while using geckodriver for Selenium using Python (in Windows 10)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mozilla, geckodriver

I've downloaded the latest version of Firefox and corresponding (64 bit) geckodriver.  Added the location of the geckodriver executable to PATH.  Yet, when I execute the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
```

to call Firefox, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Karun\Documents\NJCC all data at once Selenium.py", line 2, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Users\Karun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 162, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "C:\Users\Karun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Karun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Karun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Karun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: permission denied
```

Comment: have you restarted your computer since setting the PATH?

Comment: If this is not longer a duplicate then you need to explain why it is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing does gives us a hint about what could have gone wrong as follows :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Karun\Documents\NJCC all data at once Selenium.py", line 2, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: permission denied
```

Though you mentioned that you have *added the location of the geckodriver executable to PATH* but still facing the above mentioned error, so a simple solution will be to download the latest *GeckoDriver* from [*mozilla/geckodriver*](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and pass the *Key* `executable_path` along with the *Value* of the absolute path of the *GeckoDriver* binary while initializing the *webdriver* and *Web Browser* instance as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

Additionally ensure that you are using :

- The latest *JDK* version i.e. [*Java SE Development Kit 8u161*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
- The latest *Selenium Python Client* i.e. [*Selenium 3.9.0*](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)
- The latest *GeckoDriver* i.e. [*GeckoDriver v0.19.1*](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)
- The latest *Firefox* version i.e. *Firefox Quantum v58.0.2*
- Clean the *Project Space* from your *IDE* before and after your *Tests*.
- Run [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off the OS chores before and after executing your *Test Suite*.
- If the base version of *Firefox* is too old uninstall *Firefox* through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA released version of *Firefox*.
- Execute your *Tests*.

Comment: Thank you all for your contributions.  I removed all instances of geckodriver from my hard drive and reinstalled the driver, made sure that PATH included the directory where I installed the driver and restarted my system.  And now it works fine.  So it was probably a case of duplication of some sort.  Thank you - appreciate your feedback.